# Applying `upcase`/`downcase` on every other input in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

In the below code, how do I make my five user inputs all caps on array 0,2,5 and array 1,3 lowercase? The rest of the code is working fine, just can't find that output.

```
test = []
puts "Please type 5 different words when you're ready-"
5.times do
  test << gets.chomp
end
test.sort.each do |input|
  puts "testing this: " + input.upcase
end
```

Comment: Using with_index you can check for evenly divisible by 2, and do the one thing you want, and leave it natural when it is not evenly divisible.

Comment: way to complicated.. I'm new to this so still learning the methods :) @CarySwoveland

Comment: Your title does not match your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically asking how to apply different transformations to an array depending on the index of the specific item. With Ruby you can chain `with_index` onto enumerators and then use the index inside your enumerator block as you loop through each array item. In order to transform an array into a new one, you will need to use `map`.

```
transformed_tests = tests.map.with_index do |test, index|
  if index.even?
    test.upcase
  else
    test.downcase
  end
end
```

or, a more compact version:

```
transformed_tests = tests.map.with_index do |test, index|
  test.send(index.even? ? :upcase : :downcase)
end
```

If you want to make the transform whilst collecting the input:

```
tests = 5.times.map do |index|
  input = gets.chomp
  input.send index.even? ? :upcase : :downcase
end
```

Comment: this is good, do you see a way to do this without transforming the array into a new one? 
I thought it was possible, but maybe that is what i'm missing

Comment: If you want to replace the existing array, use `map!` rather than `map`.  http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-map-21

The Ruby convention is to use an exclamation mark (known as a bang method) for "destructive" methods (but only when there exists a non-destructive counterpart method)

Comment: Also, bear in mind that your `sort` method needs to change to `sort!` for the same reason. Although I'm not sure why you need to sort those inputs?

Answer (score 0):

You want a simple way?

```
n = 5

test = []
(n/2).times.with_object([]) do
  test << gets.chomp.upcase
  test << gets.chomp
end
test << gets.chomp.upcase if n.even?
```

More Rubylike:

```
n.times.with_object([]) do |i,test| 
  str = gets.chomp
  str.upcase! if i.odd?
  test << str
end
```